# How to Display ArrayList in in view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Here I create a simple ArrayList. How can I display all the names in `<ul>  <li>` in Viewpage

```
public ActionResult ArrayList()
        {
            ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
            list.Add(12);
            list.Add("Ghouse");
            list.Add(12.258);
            foreach(var xx in list)
            {

                ViewBag.ArrayList = xx;

            }
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: could u plz  Give complete syntax in view

Comment: A couple of remarks: **(1)** `ArrayList` is an antique and very primitive collection from the .NET 1.x era. Its elements are all of type `object`, meaning that there are no *type-checks* on `Add`, and you need to *type-check* and/or *type-cast*  when using the items - horrible! Better use a strong typed `List<T>`. Or create a class if you need to gather and hold values of different types. **(2)** Your `foreach` assigns multiple `xx` values to the same `ViewBag.ArrayList` item. Only the last one will remain because every assignment overwrites the previous one.

Answer (score 3):

You add arrayList to Viewbag:

```
ViewBag.data = list;
```

Then display the Viewbag in View :

```
 foreach (var list in ViewBag.data)
{
    <li>@list</li>
}
```